# Vue.js with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vue.js

I just started trying out `Vue.js` and applying it to an existing `ASP.NET MVC 5` application.

The app has a form with a number of input controls:

```
<div id="vueApp">
    ...
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FullName, new { @v_model = "fullName", @class = "form-control input" })

    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Branch, new { @v_model = "branch", @class = "form-control input" })
```

Some where at the end there's a summary to let users review the data before submitting:

```
<label>Name</label>: {{ fullName }}

<label>Branch</label>: {{ branch }}
```

The script is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    myObject = new Vue({
        el: '#vueApp',
        data: {
            fullName: '',
            branch: ''
        }
    })
</script>
```

This works fine if starting with all fields empty. However, if some fields are initialized with values from the server, or when used to Edit existing records, the fields are shown as empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be more elegant way to do this but one simple way I think that should work is to update your script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var fullNameVal = $('#FullName').val();
    var branchVal = $('#Branch').val();

    myObject = new Vue({
        el: '#vueApp',
        data: {
            fullName: fullNameVal,
            branch: branchVal
        }
    })
</script>
```

Comment: I'm going to try this out later as I don't have my dev machine with me right now. This looks promising though.